# Write an equation, but I have a word with an accent

Tags: equations, accents

I want to write this equation: Peso fibra=(1,266x500)/(média 3 pesos)

I used the equation environment. But, the word "média" has an accent. So, I have problems to compile my main file.

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Consider putting `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but maybe the following is what you are after:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \text{Peso fibra}
  = (1{,}266 \times 500)/(\text{m\'edia 3 pesos})
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: `\text{m\'edia $3$ pesos}` is better, IMO.

Comment: @egreg Good point! I'll change it.

Comment: For the denominator, `\text{m\'edia 3 pesos}` would seem more straightforward.

Comment: @Mico I think `3` should be in math mode.

Comment: I guess this might matter if the fonts used for math and text mode aren't the same.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `\'e` for the accent. For the text in math mode, use `\mbox{}` or `\text{}` from `amsmath` packages. This is the sample code to generate the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \mbox{Peso fibra} = \frac{(1,266\times500)}{\mbox{m\'edia 3 pesos}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

> all possibility

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{units}

\begin{document}
    The simple one (without \verb|amsmath| package),
    \begin{align*}
        \mbox{Peso fibra} &=(1,266\times500)/(\mbox{m\'edia 3 pesos})
        \\
        \mbox{Peso fibra} &= \frac{(1,266\times500)}{\mbox{m\'edia 3 pesos}}
        \\
        \mbox{Peso fibra} &= \nicefrac{(1,266\times500)}{(\mbox{m\'edia 3 pesos})}
    \end{align*}

    With \verb|\text{}| from \verb|amsmath|
    \begin{align*}
        \text{Peso fibra} &=(1,266\times500)/(\text{m\'edia 3 pesos})
        \\
        \text{Peso fibra} &= \frac{(1,266\times500)}{\text{m\'edia 3 pesos}}
        \\
        \text{Peso fibra} &= \nicefrac{(1,266\times500)}{(\text{m\'edia 3 pesos})}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's better to use the `\text` macro in this situation as the font size will adjust automatically if the string occurs in the numerator or denominator of a fraction.